# Python Script Not Running

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am relatively new to python and have setup a local virtualenviorenment on my mac desktop. I am utilizing the Flask, jsonify, and requests frameworks.

Inside of myvirtualenviorenment I have two files: one that just uses flask and one which uses flask, jsonify, and requests frameworks. I believe I have imported all these frameworks correctly, but when I run the second file, which is a GET request, using all 3 frameworks, I dont get a response at all from terminal.

However, I am able to access 127.0.0.1:5000 when just using the Flask framework. Did I not properly import the jsonify and request frameworks?

Below is my code for the non-working file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request #import objects from the Flask model
app = Flask(__name__) #define app using Flask

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return jsonify({'message' : 'It works!'})

    if __name__== '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, port=8080) #run app on port 8080 in debug mode
```

Comment: Which file did you run? this exact one?

Comment: correct. this is the non-working file that I have tried running. does it have something to do with the port being 8080?

Comment: Try to access you server on http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: well i am trying to run: python restful.py (my file name, and what is shown above), but nothing happens. how can i change my sever to port 8080 when running python?

Comment: You have set the port to be 8080, so what you want to do now is just running this file and accessing http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: what would the terminal python command look like to achieve that? and thanks for your help!

Comment: You can run `python app.py` with `app.py` the file that contains the above code

Comment: i try exactly that but nothing happens: python restful.py

Comment: Please also show us the code of the other file you are referring to. Also, how are you running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go ahead and unindent

```
if __name__== '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, port=8080) #run app on port 8080 in debug mode
```

Running this file with python will now start the development server.

Comment: it was an indentation issue after all...i feel silly. thank you for catching this

Comment: You're welcome. Later, when you build bigger projects, you may have a file `run.py` that contains only the app.run part so you keep your project modularized.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation seems wrong 
`def test()` should not be indented, is this the way the code is written or just the way you copied?
The same goes to `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: This shoud be just a comment, not an answer!

Comment: i actually messed it up indenting it in stackoverflow. i have corrected it above and it now reflects what my code actually looks like with indentations.

Comment: That could have been the reason the code is not working